# django set user object as field value on form submit

Tags: django

My model has a required foreign key to the Users model. On the form submit I'd like to save the logged in user as the submitter.

In my view:

```
def myview(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    myuser = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    form.submitter_field = myuser
    if form.is_valid()
      #this prints a failed message saying submitter_field is required
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you. You can get the user id from the request session without running the user query.

```
if form.is_valid(): 
    f = form.save(commit=false)
    f.submitter_field = request.user
    f.save()
```

Comment: The submitter field is required, so I can't call `is_valid()` before I set the field. Doing `form.save(commit=False)` before `is_valid()` throws and error: `could not be created because the data didn't validate.
`

Comment: If the submitter field is required by your form, just remove it from the form or set the submitter field required=False. You can also set the initial value in your form for the submitter field by doing `form = MyForm(request.POST or None, initial={ 'submitter': request.user})`